# Extracting stubborn plants from styroblocks

Tags: production-methods

At times you invert the pot and tap, and it pops out.  Other times, it can be stubborn.

I grow a lot of trees in styroblocks. (https://bpgrower.com/styroblockcontainers)  Typically they spend 2 years in the block then get transplanted to a bigger pot.  Sometimes they are unwilling to come out.  Roots have gotten between the granules in the block.

- First method.   Grab stem and pull.  Sometimes this wrecks the tree, when the bark slips, sometimes it tree leaves half it's roots and most of the dirt in the block.
- Second method.  Push with finger on the root ball.  This only can be done with the 1 liter blocks. This is really hard on the finger after a dozen or two.
- Third method:  Cut a scrap of plywood about 2" square and 1/2" thick.  Drill a hole 3/4" in diameter.  Screw this onto a Gardena hand nozzle that has garden hose threads on the output of the nozzle.
  Turn the tap on to a quarter flow. You want a flow of about a half cup per second wide open.  Not enough: waiting...  Too much: hard to control.
  Press this firm against the drainage hole. Squeeze trigger.
  This method will frequently get you soaked. Sometimes it will only move the root ball enough for the water to go around the root, but leave it stuck.
- Fourth method: Destroy the block.  Blocks cost about $4.50 each, or about 30 cents per tree. Normal use is about 10 years.

---

New methods I've not tried yet:

- Replace water with air.  While this will keep me drier, I suspect that it will have more problems with air escaping around the root plug.
- This is basically an improved mechanical finger. Take a toggle bolt drywall anchor (Hillman group).  Reverse the toggle.  Put a handle on the bolt.  Now insert into drainage hole and push.  The bolt wings expabd pushing against more of the root plug.
- Shape a sheet metal tool to match the curve of the plug.  Use this to cut the roots by plunging down the sides of the root ball from the top.  This is much like using a dinner knife to loosen the edges of the loaf when extracting banana nut bread from the pan.

There are manual pin extractors that purport to do this.  On stubborn trees, the pins just sink into the root ball.  (See https://plugpopper.com)

Other ideas that may be easier/faster.

Comment: I have never seen this product before.  Just read the bulletin... wow.  This seems like an incredible tool.  Have you contacted the manufacturer?

Comment: These are standard for growing forestry seedlings.  Commercially they sell them by the tens of thousands.  They are more expensive than plastic bedding plant trays (about $4.50 vs 30 c.  But they are rigid enough that you don't need benches.  Pipes or angle iron laid across cinder blocks.  Commercial extractors operate hydraulically and push out 12 rows a minute onto a conveyor belt -- and cost 100K.